# Initializing order of SQL rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Currently, we always fetch rows of a table in certain order:

```
SELECT ... FROM table_x WHERE ... ORDER BY ...
```

However, we want to make the order customizable by user with drag'n'drop (yes, in this case it actually makes sense, where-clause typically ensures it is 5-30 rows only). For this purpose we create column `sequence_order` and from now on rows will be sorted on it when selecting.

The problem is that we already have millions of rows in `table_x`. When we roll out this new feature, we want the order *initially*, before any customizations by the users, to be the same as before. I.e. we'd need to perform

```
UPDATE table_x SET sequence_number = ...
```

of some sort when upgrading the database.

The problem is that I don't even see how to use original order-by-clause to ensure that rows are updated in the correct order. Is this possible, or do I need to use some higher-level scripting?

We use Oracle database, so Oracle-specific constructs are OK.

**EDIT**

As a simplified example: I need a statement that writes 1, 2, 3 ... into column `sequence_order` of `table_x` in alphabetical order of column `name`. Something like this in pseudo-SQL:

```
UPDATE table_x SET sequence_number = ... -- for all rows ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add sequence in a new column `sequence_number` which should be `order by` `name`.

One way I can think of is below, but it would skip some numbers if `name` are duplicate.

Create a sequence

```
create sequence myseq01 start with 1 increment by 1;
```

Now run this `plsql` block.

```
declare
cursor crsr is select name from table_x order by name;
BEGIN
for rec in crsr loop
 update table_x set sequence_number = myseq01.nextval where name=rec.name;
end loop;
-- COMMIT; --Use it only when you understand what the PLSQL block is doing.
END;
```

I strongly suggest to use it only if you can afford to skip some numbers in sequence( but they will be unique).

Also make sure auto_commit is off and remove the commit from the PLSQL block as well to make sure you are not updating it incorrectly.

Comment: Looks good, thank you. What if I want to initialize to some different sequence (not 1, 2, 3, ...), can I just use two cursors and update rows from the first with a value fetched from the second?

Comment: If you want to initialize different sequence, you can use a counter variable before `loop` and use that in update statement, and then increment it.

Comment: Incrementing is not really enough. It is in increasing order, but the values are really non-sequential, like 100, 150, 155, 191 etc. So I'd want to be able to select from a table, because there is no way algorithmically recreate this.